# How do I place a thumbnail of items in a product package on the cart page?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-1.8

I'm trying to place the thumbnail of items of product package on the cart page.
I tried this code:

```
<img class="thumbnail"
                     src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(true)->resize(80, 80); ?>"
                     alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()) ?>"
                     title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getImageLabel()); ?>" />
```

In this archive:
**app/design/frontend/default/my-theme/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml**

[Screenshot of cart page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp9Bq.png)

And this shows only default thumbnail image.

What code can I use to solve this?

My magento version:  1.9.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Please try $this->getProductThumbnail(), I think this should be works. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Raj for the support. I'm not a programmer. I tried the following way <img src="<? php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->init($_ item, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(true)->resize (80, 80); ?>" /> and nothing has changed . I also tried this <? php echo $this->getProductThumbnail() ?>. But in this case it returns the image of the package of products and not of the items of the package